# Difference between independent Normal variables- is textbook answer wrong?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

This question subtracts two independent random Normal variables. I don't understand the order they subtracted the variables:

[image]

Because runner A will win, B's time will be greater, so for A to win by more than 0.5 seconds I did:

D = B - A

P(D > 0.5)

However, the answer has D = A - B:

[image]

If A won the race, then A - B would give a negative number and D > 0.5 makes no sense?

Comment: I think you may be correct. If $D=A-B$ then the desired event is $D < -0.05$ with probability about $0.306$ (assuming head-to-head does not affect the independence)

Answer (score -1):

First, one must assume that past running times are
normally distributed and relevant to the proposed race between A and B. Second, one must assume that, when
racing each other, their running times remain independent, which does not seem likely in practice.

At first glance, one might think that B is bound to win because B has the lower mean running time for such races. However, because of variations in running times, there is a substantial probability that either runner may win.

Presumably, we could resolve really close races
with a photograph, but we are looking for **decisive**
wins in which the difference is more than 0.5 sec.

I suppose you are expected to assume that when A and B race each other, that the distribution of the difference in finishing times can be found
using the usual rules for subtracting
independent normal random variables.

Here is a simulation based on ten million races (under the assumptions above), with
probabilities that should be accurate to about three places.

```
set.seed(2022)
a = rnorm(10^7, 13.2, .9)
b = rnorm(10^7, 12.9, 1.3)
mean(a < b)                   # A wins
[1] 0.4245494
mean((a < b) & (abs(a-b)>.5)) # A decisive win
[1] 0.3061565                 # See Henry's Comment
mean(b < a)                   # B wins
[1] 0.5754506
mean((b < a) & (abs(a-b)>.5)) # B decisive win
[1] 0.449838                  # Book answer
```

As stated in your question, there seems to be some confusion between the
Problem and the Answer. I will leave it to you to
decide which answer is relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question is simply about combining independent random variables (which are assumed to be normally distributed). The question says A won the race by more than 0.5 seconds, so my question is surely B - A  must be > 0.5? Rather than A - B (as the answer suggests)?